# What are the <> for in an ArrayList, List or other types that use <>?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, syntax

I've Googled around but I can't find the use for the `<>` in `ArrayList` or `List`. I know how to use `ArrayList` but I like to know how things work as well. What are the `<>` for? I figure it's like an argument of sorts since it specifies the type but it's not an argument since it doesn't go in `()` so what do the `<>` mean?

Comment: See: [The Java™ Tutorials: Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

Answer (score 2):

to specify the generic type.

`List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();` will restrict only strings to be added

When you say `List strings = new ArrayList();` you are not specifying which kind of object the `strings` list accepts. So, `strings.add(new Object())` is also possible. By specifying `List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();` you restrict the arraylist to access only `String` elements.